# Android sdkmanager tool not found

Tags: android, flutter, ubuntu-18.04, android-sdk-manager

[image]I newly started using Ubuntu 18.0 LTS this week, switching from Windows, and wanted to install Android Studio and Flutter back. I followed all the steps as said to install Android Studio and it is working fine with all the SDKs. However, when I wanted to install Flutter, it gives exception:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
Unhandled exception:
Exception: Android sdkmanager tool not found (/usr/lib/android-sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager).
Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
visit https://flutter.io/setup/#android-setup for detailed instructions.
```

Ask for the stacktrace if you need it.

The closest issue I could find was: [How to install SDK manager on linux ubuntu 16.04?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45793933/how-to-install-sdk-manager-on-linux-ubuntu-16-04) but I couldn't really understand how to work the instructions. I might need you to be really clear in the instructions because I'm new to the linux platform.

**tools/package.xml :**

```
<ns2:repository xmlns:ns2="http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/common/01"
            xmlns:ns3="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/addon2/01"
            xmlns:ns4="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/sys-img2/01"
            xmlns:ns5="http://schemas.android.com/repository/android/generic/01"
            xmlns:ns6="http://schemas.android.com/sdk/android/repo/repository2/01">
      <license id="apache-2.0" type="text">Please refer to Apache v2.0 license</license>
  <localPackage path="tools" obsolete="false">
<type-details xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:type="ns5:genericDetailsType"/>
<revision>
  <major>25</major>
  <minor>0</minor>
  <micro>0</micro>
</revision>
<display-name>Android SDK Tools</display-name>
<uses-license ref="apache-2.0"/>
<dependencies>
  <dependency path="platform-tools">
    <min-revision>
      <major>20</major>
    </min-revision>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
  </localPackage>
 </ns2:repository>
```

**Flutter doctor -v output:**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.7.3, on Linux, locale en_IN)
• Flutter version 0.7.3 at /home/andi/Downloads/flutter
• Framework revision 3b309bda07 (13 days ago), 2018-08-28 12:39:24 -0700
• Engine revision af42b6dc95
• Dart version 2.1.0-dev.1.0.flutter-ccb16f7282

[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 28.0.2)
• Android SDK at /home/andi/Android/Sdk
• Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
• Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.2
• ANDROID_HOME = /home/andi/Android/Sdk
• Java binary at: /home/andi/Downloads/android-studio-ide-173.4907809-linux/android-studio/jre/bin/java
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
! Some Android licenses not accepted.  To resolve this, run: flutter doctor --android-licenses

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
• Android Studio at /home/andi/Downloads/android-studio-ide-173.4907809-linux/android-studio
• Flutter plugin version 28.0.1
• Dart plugin version 173.4700
• Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[!] Connected devices
! No devices available

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
```

Answer (score 89):

I had this issue after installed on my KUbuntu.

You need to open **AndroidStudio** then go to **Tools** -> **SDK Manager** then go to **SDK Tools** tab, uncheck the option `Hide Obsolete Packages`

You will see the option of **Android SDK Tools (Obsolete)**, check the option and continue the process download and installation.

[image: See the screenshot here]

Comment: I download android-studio-ide-192.6241897-linux.tar.gz and 
flutter_linux_v1.12.13+hotfix.8-stable.tar.xz. This is a bug of Android Studio I think.

Comment: Solved on Linux Mint 19 !!

Comment: Solved on MacOS Catalina

Comment: Solved in Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 13):

I'm using Manjaro Linux. After set my `ANDROID_HOME` and install Android **SDK Command-line tools (latest**) from Android Studio.

And ran:

[flutter doctor --android-licenses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lhf4y.png)

```
$ mkdir ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin
```

And created a link to the real path

```
$ ln -s ~/Android/Sdk/cmdline-tools/latest/bin/sdkmanager ~/Android/Sdk/tools/bin/sdkmanager
```

Ran again and accept all

```
$ flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

[flutter doctor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPgk3.png)

Comment: This should probably be the accepted answer as it uses the latest SDK tools instead of installing an older version.

Comment: This is the better and correct answer. You also don't need to create the symbolic link anymore. Flutter automatically finds the sdkmanager under `cmdline-tools`.

Answer (score 9):

If you come across this error when accepting SDK licenses.

```
➜  ~ flutter doctor --android-licenses
Android sdkmanager not found. Update to the latest Android SDK and ensure that the cmdline-tools are installed
to resolve this
```

the structure of the initial android-sdk was :

```
android-sdk
├── build-tools
│   ├── 29.0.3 -> debian
│   └── debian
│       └── lib
├── cmdline-tools
│   ├── tools
│   │   ├── bin
```

and the way i was able to configure android licenses was to change the structure of the android-sdk directory by changing 'tools' to 'latest'

```
android-sdk
├── build-tools
│   ├── 29.0.3 -> debian
│   └── debian
│       └── lib
├── cmdline-tools
│   ├── latest
│   │   ├── bin
|   |   |
```

Answer (score 9):

To fix the Android sdkmanager not found warning:

1. Open Android Studio
2. From the top toolbar, select **Tools > SDK Manager**.
3. Select the **SDK Tools tab**, with a blue underline.
4. Uncheck 'Hide Obsolete Packages'.
5. Tick `Android SDK Command-line Tools (latest)`.

[image]
6. Click **Ok**

Screenshot of Android Studio Electric Eel.

Answer (score 4):

I had this issue when I installed on Ubuntu. You need to set env variable ANDROID_HOME to the path you installed the android sdk for flutter to work.

So assuming you installed the SDK in your home directory, open a terminal and issue this command

```
ANDROID_HOME=~/Android-SDK flutter doctor
```

If that worked, then add the env variable to your profile to make it persistent, by adding

```
export ANDROID_HOME=~/Android-SDK
```

to your ~/.profile script, then relogin to Ubuntu.

Obviously if you installed the android sdk in a different directory, you just need to replace ~/ with the directory, so for example if you installed the sdk to /opt, then the command would be
    ANDROID_HOME=/opt/Android-SDK flutter doctor

Having checked my android sdk + flutter setup, I also ended up adding the following to my path

```
~/Android-SDK/platform-tools
```

You can test this before messing with your profile, by the following command in a terminal

```
PATH=$PATH:~/Android-SDK/platform-tools ANDROID_HOME=~/Android-SDK flutter doctor
```

And again change ~/Android-SDK to wherever you installed the android SDK. If it works, change your profile accordingly and relogin to Ubuntu.

Comment: No, the first command didn't work. If it helps, I followed https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26256279/how-to-set-android-home-path-in-ubuntu-please-provide-the-steps to set the variable.

Comment: @AdityaNigam I found setting up flutter to play nicely with android sdk a pita, and I'm experienced with linux, so don't despair. I added something new to my answer, give it a try.

Comment: @AdityaNigam It looks like those instructions you followed in that other link told you to put the export in .bashrc which is okay but will only affect the bash cli shell, so if you run your sdk from the cli, it's good. But if you run from the gui, you may find problems, whereas the .profile script sets up the environment for other shells, so I would (as I did) recommend setting up your envrionment in your .profile script.

Comment: So i did gedit ~/.profile and in the end added **export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"** . Also, did you want me to put the flutter sdk folder into the same location? Because it still says **flutter: command not found**

Comment: @AdityaNigam Your flutter can be anywhere as long as you setup the environment to point to it, and the fact that your flutter doctor command is running suggests that you have, so leave it as it is. The only things I have setup in my .profile script concerning android are export **PATH="$HOME/Android-SDK/platform-tools":$HOME/android-studio/bin:"$PATH"** and **export ANDROID_HOME=$HOME/Android-SDK**, and although it was a long time ago, that's all I remember having to do. I stopped using flutter, preferring plain java sdk, so I guess things might have changed.

Comment: Remember that you have to logout and login to Ubuntu after changing .profile for the changes to take effect.

Comment: I did that, and I guess adding the path like you said helped it too, thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I'm always puzzled why an installation package shouldn't contain all necessary dependencies but cause trouble (perhaps fun) to so many people?

Anyway, I'd like to add something to the [zmofsx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12993756/zmofsx) [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490042/505539) because, for me, the solution didn't fix the problem completely, and I had to do a few more steps described below.

Hope those may help someone in troubleshooting.

So after the steps described [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490042/505539), I did the following in the console:

```
flutter doctor --android-licenses
```

Hit Y to show all the licences and Y to each of them. Then

```
flutter doctor
```

And this is my console output:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.0.5, on Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS 5.4.0-122-generic, locale en_GB.UTF-8)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 33.0.0)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Linux toolchain - develop for Linux desktop
[✓] Android Studio (version 2021.2)
[✓] Android Studio
[✓] VS Code (version 1.69.2)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)
[✓] HTTP Host Availability

• No issues found!
```

Then tested the result:

```
mkdir flutter_example
cd flutter_example
flutter create .
flutter run -d linux
```

And got the app running:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

For those using pop_os 22 and have installed the android studio using flatpak
the problem is that the android studio is isolated so you need to config the path for android-sdk and android-studio-dir

```
flutter config --android-sdk ~/Android/Sdk
flutter config -android-studio-dir path/android-studio
```

for pop_os installed from shop you'll find it here /home//.local/share/flatpak/app/com.google.AndroidStudio/current/active/files/extra/android-studio

then you will run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` and accepts all licenses so now `flutter doctor` will not show a error.

Answer (score 0):

use the tool of config from Flutter

```bash
flutter config --android-sdk ~/Android/Sdk/
flutter config --android-studio-dir ~/android-studio/
```

after accept licences
`flutter doctor --android-licenses`

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling android studio can fix this issue.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).