# Flutter installation error - Android sdk file not found: ....... aapt?

Tags: android, flutter, installation

When i run a hello world application in flutter

it show

```
Unable to locate a development device; please run 'flutter doctor' for information about installing additional components.
```

```
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\hi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    X Android SDK file not found: C:\Users\hi\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\29.0.2\aapt.
    • Try re-installing or updating your Android SDK,
      visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for detailed instructions.

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

then i tried flutter doctor

after that i get this ..

Comment: please see this [https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490042/13039581](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60490042/13039581) I hope it can help you

Comment: but the issue, is i download the android sdk build tools 29.0.2 then i cannot find the aapt file ..

Answer (score 14):

I spent like half a day solving this issue. For me `flutter doctor` displayed this error:

```
X Android SDK file not found: SomeLongPath/Android/sdk/build-tools/30.0.4-rc1/aapt
```

I just deleted this `30.0.4-rc1` folder because it was empty for some reason, ran `flutter doctor` and the issue is solved!

Comment: Thanks. saved a lot of my time. My installation of sdk 32.1.0-rc1 had failed due to network error. that's why the folder was empty. deleting that folder solved the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Error solved:

just uninstalling build-tools 29.0.2
and
reinstalling build-tools 29.0.2 in sdk manager android studio

thank you,

Answer (score 2):

For my case and after wasting a full day. I was getting:

```
X Android SDK file not found: 
  C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\31.0.0-rc4\aapt.
```

So I copied C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\build-tools\ path and pasted it in a folder directory path to navigate. I deleted a folder named 31.0.0-rc4 and run:

```
 flutter doctor -v
```

again. Hope someone gets helped.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, i delete the folder on `build-tools/x.x.x` that cause the problem and run the flutter app again, it works and it install automatically the build tools needed, this the output of the app when it run

> Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /home/mde/Android/Sdk/licenses
> License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 accepted.
> Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)".
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)" ready.
> Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 in /home/mde/Android/Sdk/build-tools/29.0.2
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)" complete.
> "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 29.0.2 (revision: 29.0.2)" finished.

Answer (score 0):

Faced the same issue, on 'Android SDK version 31.0.0-rc4'. Tried to remove and reinstall `build-tools`. Didn't work. The problem was in the SDK tools folder. Removed both `build-tools` and `tools` folder. And then Installed `Android SDK Command line tools`, as well as, `Android SDK Platform-tools` again